# Why am I getting new records created in table a when I edit a record of another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have an Invoice object that has a list of items and other properties. Whenever I execute the service that edits an invoice, each item get doubled for some reason.

For example, here's a snapshot of the items table after creating an invoice with two items:
[Items table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZwzE.png)

And here's a snapshot of it after executing `EditInvoice` service: [Items table after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se6Z2.png)

### Data Model

#### Invoice

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateInvoiceID();
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDue { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; } = "pending";
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        

        public string BillFromAddress { get; set; }
        public string BillFromCity { get; set; }
        public string BillFromCountry { get; set; }
        public string BillFromPostal { get; set; }

    }
```

#### InvoiceItem

```
public class InvoiceItem
    {
        public string InvoiceItemId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateItemID();
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public InvoiceItem()
        {
        }

        public InvoiceItem(string itemName, int quantity, int price)
        {
            Name = itemName;
            Quantity = quantity;
            Price = price;
        }

    }
```

### My InputModel

```
public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

        public string PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDue { get; set; }


        public Client Client { get; set; }
        

        
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>(16);


        [Required]
        public string BillFromAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromCity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromCountry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromPostal { get; set; }


        public void PopulateItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(new InvoiceItem());
            }
        }
    }
```

### My Page Models

#### CreateInvoiceModel

```
public class CreateInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {
        
        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public CreateInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {
            Input = new InputModel();
            Input.PopulateItems();
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.AddInvoice(Input);
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            return Page();

        }

    }
```

#### EditInvoiceModel

```
public class EditInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {

        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public EditInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        
        public async void OnGet(string id)
        {
            Invoice invoice = await _service.GetInvoice(id);
            InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId;
            Input = new InputModel();

            Input.Items = invoice.Items;

            Input.BillFromAddress = invoice.BillFromAddress;
            Input.BillFromCity = invoice.BillFromCity;
            Input.BillFromPostal = invoice.BillFromPostal;
            Input.BillFromCountry = invoice.BillFromCountry;

            Input.Client = invoice.Client;

            Input.InvoiceDate = invoice.InvoiceDate;
            Input.PaymentTerms = invoice.PaymentTerms;
            Input.Description = invoice.Description;

        }

        public  async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string id)
        {
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.EditInvoice(Input, id);
                return RedirectToPage("/ViewInvoice", new { id = id });
            }

            return Page();
        }

    }
```

### Services

#### AddInvoice

```
public async void AddInvoice(InputModel input)
        {
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();


            invoice.Description = input.Description;
            invoice.Items = input.Items;
            invoice.InvoiceDate = input.InvoiceDate;
            invoice.PaymentTerms = input.PaymentTerms;
            invoice.Client = input.Client;
            

            invoice.BillFromAddress = input.BillFromAddress;
            invoice.BillFromCity = input.BillFromCity;
            invoice.BillFromCountry = input.BillFromCountry;
            invoice.BillFromPostal = input.BillFromPostal;

            //Attaching the invoice id to each item in the invoice
            foreach (var item in invoice.Items)
            {
                item.InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId;
            }

            //IndexModel.invoices.Add(invoice);
            _context.Add(invoice);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

#### EditInvoice

```
public async void EditInvoice(InputModel input, string id)
        {
            var invoice = await _context.Invoices.FindAsync(id);

            if (invoice == null) { throw new Exception("Unable to find the invoice"); }
            
            invoice.Items = input.Items;

            invoice.Description = input.Description;
            invoice.InvoiceDate = input.InvoiceDate;
            invoice.PaymentTerms = input.PaymentTerms;
            invoice.Client = input.Client;
            

            invoice.BillFromAddress = input.BillFromAddress;
            invoice.BillFromCity = input.BillFromCity;
            invoice.BillFromCountry = input.BillFromCountry;
            invoice.BillFromPostal = input.BillFromPostal;

           
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: If you comment this line `invoice.Items = input.Items;` in `EditInvoice` method, did it still create new invoice item?

Comment: No it doesn't! But now how can I add new items if want ? The reason I have this line is to update the list of items in case I make any changes related to the items.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
invoice.Items = input.Items;
```

You can work with:

1. For adding a new `InvoiceItem` record, presume the invoice item doesn't have `InvoiceId` (foreign key value), use `.Add()` as adding a new record.
2. For the existing `InvoiceItem` record, presume the invoice item has `InvoiceId` (foreign key value), set the entity, and modify its state as Modified. Make sure that the entity's Id (primary key (value)) matches with the record in the database table. Reference: [Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#attaching-an-existing-but-modified-entity-to-the-context)

```cs
public async void EditInvoice(InputModel input, string id)
{
    var invoice = await _context.Invoices.FindAsync(id);

    if (invoice == null) { throw new Exception("Unable to find the invoice"); }
            
    foreach (var item in input.Items)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InvoiceId))
        {
            invoice.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    invoice.Description = input.Description;
    invoice.InvoiceDate = input.InvoiceDate;
    invoice.PaymentTerms = input.PaymentTerms;
    invoice.Client = input.Client;
            

    invoice.BillFromAddress = input.BillFromAddress;
    invoice.BillFromCity = input.BillFromCity;
    invoice.BillFromCountry = input.BillFromCountry;
    invoice.BillFromPostal = input.BillFromPostal;

           
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Or you can work as:

```cs
foreach (var item in input.Items)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InvoiceId))
    {
        item.InvoiceId = invoice .InvoiceId;
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Insert or update pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#insert-or-update-pattern)

Although the provided documentation is regarding Entity Framework 6, it supports in [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems:

First of all in your `InvoiceItem` you have the following line

```
public string InvoiceItemId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateItemID();
```

which means that whenever n `InvoiceItem` is instanciated a new Id is generated which is not correct because there is a difference between actually **creating** an InvoiceItem and just creating an instance of the class `InvoiceItem`. A new Id should only be generated if a **new** InvoiceItem is created but not for example if an existing InvoiceItem is loaded from the database (in both cases an instance of the class `InvoiceItem` is created but only in the first one an actual InvoiceItem shall be created). So removing the id generation from the property declaration and only performing is when an InvoiceItem shall actually be created will fix this part of the problem.

The second problem is in `EditInvoice` where you call

```
var invoice = await _context.Invoices.FindAsync(id);

// ...
            
invoice.Items = input.Items;
```

in the first line you are loading the invoice from the database but you are not including the invocies and therefore they do not get loaded and EF does not even know they exist.
So when you are calling `invoice.Items = input.Items` you are assigning the list with the **new** InvoiceItems with the newly generated ids (as explained above) and they will therefore be added to the database and hence duplicated.

So instead of replacing the whole list you should be editing existing items and only adding InvoiceItems which have actually been created to the list.

Comment: How is an actual creation of an `InvoiceItem` different from creating an instance of it ? And how do I have the ID generation happens upon actual creation ? Should I have it in the constructor method ?

Comment: @user18012137 as I explained above the actual creation of an `InvoiceItem` happens when the User (or another system or whatever) decides that the item shall be created (e.g. if the customer orders another piece). But the creation of an **instance** of `InvoiceItem` can happen for various different reasons - as in your case when retrieving an existing `InvoiceItem` from the database.

Comment: When retrieving an `InvoiceItem` from the database the constructor of `InvoiceItem` is called and therefore a new **instance** of `InvoiceItem` is created - but this does not automatically mean that an `InvoiceItem` has actually been created (it already existed and was just retrieved from the database). In this case you do not want a new id to be assigned to the object because it already has an id and represents an existing database entry.

Comment: @user18012137 in my opinion the best was to differenticate between instanciation and creation is a factory method - add an **private** empty constructor to your `InvoiceItem` where you do **not** generate an id. This constructor will be automatically use by EF when retriving it from the database.

Adittionally add a public static factory methoy `Create` to your model, which creates a new instance, generates an id, assigns it to the instance and the returns the insance. SO when you actually want to create an `InvoiceItem` use the `Create` method and you get a new Id.